# How to use a Relation column in Parse.com for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation

I'm wondering on how to use the Relation column in Parse, I have been looking for this and I didn't find much information about this, I found the link below : [Parse Relations Developer Guide](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide)

But I didn't find helpful information, anyway I have a Publications Class et a Comments Class, each publication has different comments,

so how I would be able to use this, and get for example all the comments for one publication.

That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found how to do that, looking on Parse Developer Guide :

Here is how to insert comment to a publication for example :

```
 commentaire = new ParseObject("Commentaires"); 
    commentaire.put("commentaire", "test1");
    commentaire.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
       public void done(ParseException e) {
          message.getRelation("commentaires").add(commentaire);
      message.saveInBackground();
```

Retrieving is more simple :

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation("commentaires");
```

I hope this will help someone

For more info check : [Parse Developer Guide](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers)